# Questions on use of malloc() and free()

Tags: c, memory, malloc, free

Thanks for notice my question.

In C Primer Plus, it first writes

> The argument to `free()` should be a pointer to a block of memory allocated by `malloc()`; you can’t use `free()` to free memory allocated by other means

which means ONE `malloc()`, ONE and *ONLY* one `free()`.

But later it goes

> It’s okay to use a different pointer variable with `free()` than with `malloc()`; what must agree are the addresses stored in the pointers.

which seems contradict to the first statement.

So my understanding is that as long as a pair of `malloc()` and `free()` share the same address there is no error, and the name of pointers doesn't matter. Am I right?

Comment: "The argument to free() **should** be a ..." is wrong. It **shall** be. And a pointer is not the object it **points to**!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For example:

```
void* p = malloc (100);
void* q = p;
free (q);
```

...is fine. The argument for `free ()` is the value that was returned by `malloc`. The sentence

> "It’s okay to use a different pointer variable with free() than with
>   malloc()"

is actually pointless and just creates confusion - of course it is fine to use different variables as long as the value is the same.

Comment: Thanks, this book seems to have many redundant description like this

Answer (score 5):

Just remember that freeing any alias, makes all the pointers invalid

```
int *a, *b, *c, *d, *e;
a = malloc(42 * sizeof (int));
b = a;
c = b;
d = c;
e = d;
a[0] = 42;
b[1] = 100; // same as a[1]
c[2] = 999; // same as a[2]
d[3] = -1;  // same as a[3]
e[4] = 0;   // same as a[4]
free(d); // for example
// all of a, b, c, d, and e are now invalid;
```

Answer (score 2):

Variables contain some value, which could be a pointer (i.e. a memory address).

Two variables could contain the same pointer (that is, the same address), it is called pointer aliasing.

What matters to `free` is to get the *value* of a pointer previously given by `malloc` (that is a memory address previously given by `malloc`)